# Grails good BDD framework

Tags: grails, groovy, rspec, bdd

Is there RSpec analogue for Groovy/Grails?

I found a few blog posts mentioning GSpec but there is not much out there.

Is built-in Grails testing framework as good as it gets in Grails?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grails offers various other testing frameworks through the use of plugins. For instance the [Spock plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/spock) simplifies testing using a very expressive natural language. You can find more information on Spock [here as well](http://code.google.com/p/spock/).

Another popular testing framework for Grails is EasyB. It also has a [plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/easyb).

I would recommend you look at the various testing frameworks available, then see how they are supported by Grails.

Comment: OPINION: It looks like grails-cucumber gives you more mature integration testing framework than EasyB. As for specs, both EasyB and Spock do an ok job. I like Spock more as you can define multiple contexts in the same file.